# How to debug in Docker, Windows 10, WSL 2

Tags: visual-studio, docker, debugging, windows-10

When I try to run Debug F5 from VS 2019 using Docker
I see the following error

> C:\Users\comet.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.9.10\build\Container.targets(198,5):
> error CTC1001: Volume sharing is not enabled. On the Settings screen
> in Docker Desktop, click Shared Drives, and select the drive(s)
> containing your project files.

I have WSL2 and latest Docker Desktop, google says that sharing is already done
automatically so Desktop has no such Setting at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with an older project. Creating a new project with docker support worked fine. The difference I found that the old project file had:

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```

and the new project did not have that line, so I removed it. Also updated the targets:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.10.9" />
```

This solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

To start docker in WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04

```
first start wsl2
```

then run the command below to start docker daemon

```
sudo /etc/init.d/docker start
```